# Stride integrated in WPF or WinUI desktop app

Tags: c#, stride

I am using stride 3D engine integrated in an UWP application because stride only support this platform.

Do you know if it is possible (or one day) to integrate stride in a WPF or WinUI application because UWP has been declared obsolete ?

Thanks for your reply.

Regards.

Comment: UWP has been declared obsolete? Microsoft's documentation about it seems to say it's alive and kicking! Could you tell us a bit more in details what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I believe OP is talking about https://github.com/stride3d/stride/discussions/1514 given that https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/1055 given that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-1#tabpanel_1_net-standard-2-1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, see here: https://github.com/Doprez/Awesome-Stride#embedded-stride